# ¿Como puedo multiplicar un numero por posición? Python

Tags: python

Quiero realizar un programa con las siguientes instrucciones:

Se necesitan dos cadenas de 16 digitos.

C1: 4915110176928790

C2: 4915110191768499

Luego estas cadenas las divide en grupos de 8 digitos:

C1: [49151101][76928790]

C2: [49151101][91768499]

Luego tiene que agarrar C2 y multiplicar de la siguiente manera:

C2: [49151101][91768499]

El primer dígito del primer grupo de 8 por el primer dígito del segundo grupo y así sucesivamente:

4 * 9 = 36

9 * 1 = 9

1 * 7 = 7

5 * 6 = 30

1 * 8 = 8

1 * 4 = 4

0 * 9 = 0

1 * 9 = 9

Luego, el resultado de cada multiplicación lo va a pegar en una sola cadena:

**3697308409**

Como pueden ver la cadena es de 10 dígitos, así que le borramos los dos últimos dígitos, quedando una cadena de 8:

**36973084**

Ahora, tiene que pegar el primer grupo de la C1 con el resultado anterior :

**49151101**36973084

Bien luego de eso tiene que comparar similitud en el segundo grupo entre ambas cadenas, si son iguales se deja como esta pero si no lo son se remplaza por **x**:

C1: 49151101 76928790

C2: 49151101 36973084

El resultado seria:  49151101**x69xxxxx**

Ahora si el ultimo dígito de este resultado termina siendo un **x** que se remplace por 1, si no se deja como esta.

Yo intente hacerlo pero no consigo multiplicar cadenas rebanadas.

```
def metodo():
   c1= "4915110191768499"
   t1 = c1[:8]
   t1_2 = c1[8:]
   c1 = int(c1)
   for i in (len(t1)):
       if t1[i] < t1_2[i]:
           r = t1 * t1_2
       print(r)      


print( metodo())
```

Comment: Añade lo que has intentado, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mult(c1, c2)
    a= "".join([str(int(x) * int(y)) for x, y in zip(c2[:8], c2[8:])])[:8]
    b = "".join([x if x == y else "x" for x, y in zip(c1[8:], a)])
    if b[-1] == 'x':
        b = b[:-1] + "1"
    return c1[:8] + b

v1 = "4915110176928790"
v2 = "4915110191768499"
print(mult(v1, v2))
```

produce:

```
49151101x69xxxx1
```

**Explicación**

```
a= "".join([str(int(x) * int(y)) for x, y in zip(c2[:8], c2[8:])])[:8]
```

La función zip toma dos o mas iterables y produce secuencia de tupla, asi que

```
for x, y in zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]):
    print(x, y)
```

produce

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Teniendo los valores emparejados, solo queda multiplicar y convertirlos de vuelta a una lista de strings:

```
[str(int(x) * int(y)) for x, y in zip(c2[:8], c2[8:])]
```

Finalmente, juntamos todos en un sólo string usando `join`

```
a= "".join([str(int(x) * int(y)) for x, y in zip(c2[:8], c2[8:])])[:8]
```

El calculo de "b" sigue la misma técnica.

Answer (score 1):

```
C1= "4915110176928790"

C2= "4915110191768499"

C11 = C1[0:8]
#No es necesario la segunda mitad de C1
# C12 = C1[8:16]

C21 = C2[0:8]
C22 = C2[8:16]

C2 =C11+ ''.join(str(int(C21[i]) * int(C22[i])) for i in range(8))[0:8]

C2 = C2[0:8] + ''.join(C2[i] if C1[i] == C2[i] else "1" if i == 15 else 'x' for i in range(8, 16))

print(C2)
```

Para este caso la respuesta es: 49151101x69xxxx1

Para el caso:

C1: 4915110176928794

C2: 4915110191768499

La respuesta es:

49151101x69xxxx4

Comment: la idea es que el que pregunta agregue lo que intenta y ahi poder ayudarlo, no hacerles la tarea.

Comment: @SalvadorMellado  Mi idea no es solucionar el problema o que los demás lo hagan por mi, si no que como estoy aprendiendo python, al preguntar puedo estudiar y analizar lo que sucede en el código, y ver los diferentes métodos los cuales puedo utilizar.

Comment: y habías intentado algo ? como consejo a la próxima te recomiendo que añadas lo que intentaste para analizar tu código y mostrarte tu error, preguntas que solo muestran texto aveces no son bien recibidas.

Comment: Si intente pero la verdad es que no se como funcionan algunas cosas y pues me da error, preguntando me quito las dudas. Edite la publicación para que vean lo que intente.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sería:

```
def mult(cad,cad2):
  #separar números d1=cad, d2=cad2
  d1_1=cad[:8]
  d1_2=cad[8:17]

  d2_1=cad2[:8]
  d2_2=cad2[8:17]

  #multiplicar
  n=''
  for x in range(len(d1_1)):
    m=int(d1_1[x])*int(d2_2[x])
    n=n+str(m)
  
  n=n[:8]
  
  res=d1_1+n
#sustituir por 1 cuando son diferentes
  for y in range(len(cad)):
    if cad[y]!=res[y]:
     res=list(res)
     res[y]='1'
     res=''.join(res)

  return res
  

print(mult('4915110176928790','4915110191768499'))
```

la función te retorna: 4915110116911111
si es la respuesta que buscas, en caso de querer las Xs sustituye el '1' por 'x'.